# How to create a simple React Native Chatbot with react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: react-native, chatbot, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm a new in react native, and I want to create a simple chatbot with react-native-gifted-chat.

I've tried this tutorial https://youtu.be/ClBC93WPkmw, but it doesn't works because of some problem about installing Dialogflow(I've tried any other way but still can't fix).

Is there other simple way to create a simple chatbot with react-native-gifted-chat?